# Error trying to publish immediately. Post status = future (Missed schedule error)

Tags: errors, wp-cron, publish, scheduled-posts, cloudflare

We have moved a to new server and now we can’t publish. At least, we can’t publish instantly.

> Maybe can be useful: we are using Plesk & CloudFlare.

When we publish a new post, the `post_status` value in `wp_posts` table is, automatically, **`future`** instead of `publish`

We have already taken a look at this post with no lucky:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/publish-immediately-missing-and-scheduled-posts-fails/

What we have already done is:

- Checked server time
- Everything OK into site health info
- Disabled all plugins & changed to default theme
- Disabled WP Cron and setted custom cron
- Installed `My Missed Schedule` and `WP Control` plugins
  *(thanks to the first one, a cron event that is running each 5 minutes forces to publish missed scheduled post)*.
- Installed wp-cli and trying to run with `wp cron event run publish_future_post --due-now` with no lucky
- Checked PHP extensions [according to this](https://github.com/johnbillion/ext)
- An exact backup in my localhost is working like a charm

Here are some snapshots when trying to publish a post at 12:57pm…
[image: Missed schedule]

And here the cron thas is created just after trying to publish:
[image: cron list]

This is how `post_date` & `post_date_gmt` looks on the database:
[image: post date]

And this is how the time looks in WP:
[image: wordpress time]

So, until 2 hours later, the post isn't published...
This is being a nightmare. We can't use, for example, the ACF plugin. We add a new field, and it doesn't appear until 2 hours later...

Any clue?

Comment: Have you tried to change the time WP uses from UTC to something else? A lot of people see that times and dates are stored as UTC timestamps and try to force them to the local time, not realising the concept of timestamps vs time, and in the process they break a lot of time and date related things like this. E.g. is your local time UTC +2 or -2?

Comment: My local time is UTC +2 and server time outputs:
mar jul 21 10:38:20 CEST 2020

PS: I've updated the post with a new snapshot showing post_date into database.

Comment: @TomJNowell I've tried to change WP time from UTC +2 to Madrid and same behavior

Comment: hmm your server thinks that local time and universal time are the same. This implies that it thinks it's in the UTC timezone, but is 2 hours out of sync from actual UTC time. Did you change the time to match local time without changing the timezone? It should show local time as 2 hours ahead of UTC. Have you confirmed no theme or plugin is interfering by disabling them and reproducing the problem on a clean slate? PHP/your server is mistaken as to what time it is in UTC. You should confirm at the server level that the time is correct for the set timezone of your server

Comment: Good point @TomJNowell Local and universal time are the same in WP, haven't seen that...! ``timedatectl`` outputs correct Universal time and correct Local time (+2).
No plugin or theme interfering. Same behavior in a clean installation on that server... Now I'm trying how to fix the time shown in Settings. Checking timezones on PHP, Plesk, etc. I'm hoping that fixing there, the issue disappears... I'll let you know

Answer (score 2):

So the issue in this case was that PHP wasn't displaying correct UTC Time. Thanks to @TomJNowell for pointing me in the right way.

It seems to be a bug/error in some Plesk installation: https://talk.plesk.com/threads/utc-time-issue-plesk-php-7-3-7-4-on-centos7.356169/

To solve the issue we have replaced the UTC file `usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC` with another copy from another server.

After that, UTC time and Local time appears perfect and we can be able to publish inmediately.